# CLLocationManager on iPhone Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, cllocationmanager

I'm finding that on the third run of my application on the simulator, `CLLocationManager` doesn't send any `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` messages to its `delegate`.

When I say "Run", I mean a Run from the Product->Run menu in Xcode.

- On the first run, the delegate gets one `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`.
- On the second run, the delegate gets one `locationManager:didFailWithError:` and then one `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`.
- On third and subsequent runs, the delegate just gets `locationManager:didFailWithError:`

If I `po error` in the debugger I get:

> Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"

If I quit the simulator and then start it up again, the pattern will repeat with only the first two runs getting updates.

Has anyone else seen this? Any tips to make it go away?

---

I'm using Simulator 7.1, Xcode 5.1.1 (not the current Beta), and iOS 7.1 on a simulated 3.5" Retina device.

Comment: briefly, use _real_ device for testing any feature of `CoreLocation.framework`.

Comment: :-) That certainly a solution, and I appreciate the brevity, thanks!